# I keep getting an unknown error saying expected expression:

Tags: c, syntax-error, expression, cs50

```
readability.c:28:9: error: expected expression
    else:
```

Shown above is the error I am getting. If anyone would point me to what exactly I am doing wrong. that would be great. Bellow, I will add my Readability code written so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *string = get_string("Enter a string:\n");
    int i = 0;
    int char_count = 0;
    int alp = 0;
    int word = 0;
    int sentance = 0;
    while(string[i]!='\0')
    {
        if((string[i]>='a' && string[i]<='z') || (string[i]>='A' && string[i]<='Z'))
        {
            alp++;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((string[i] = ' ') || (string[i] = '.') || (string[i] = '!') || (string[i] = '?') || (string[i] = ','))
            {
                word++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ((string[i] = '.') || (string[i] = '!') || (string[i] = '?'))
            {
                sentance++;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%i\n", alp);
    printf("%i\n",word);
    printf("%i\n",sentance);
}
```

So the error is somewhere on the line 28. I am assuming my "else" statement syntax is wrong, but considering it is identical to the line above, I can't figure out what is wrong. The code worked just fine before the line 28 was added

Comment: To begin with, cange `=` to `==` in each one of these `if` statements!

Comment: As with regards to the error itself, your first `else` should be `else if` (instead of `else { if...`).

Comment: @goodvibration it seems an answer to me.

Comment: There's no "a" in "sentence".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if else statements don’t match.
Your first if is fine, it’s followed by and else.
Inside that else, you have an if statement. Now after that you have another else!

Like this:

```
if {..}
else { 
    if {...}
}
else {...}
```

It’s not matched I guess your last else should be within the first else, tied to the if inside it. Or I don’t know what you want... maybe you wanted else if?

Comment: The way I see it I have:
if
else if
else if

Comment: @igortadic You're seeing it wrong.  The second `if` is inside a block, and does no associate with any higher-level `else`.  So you have `if {} else {} else {}` which is a syntax error.  It does not match the grammar rules of C, and it makes no sense.  Get rid of the curly braces after the first `else` if you want an `if`-`else`-`if`-`else` chain.

Comment: I think I confused if else with else if. I started learning python so correct me if I am wrong. I would like it to be:
if --
elif
elif.

What would that look like in C?

Comment: Exactly as you said , instead of elif, should be else if {}

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, Your second else is correct as long as you don't use third else, bcoz else is a last statement in an if...else statement.
Now logically what you want can be achieved by removing all else and its corresponding braces.